# No Adobe Flash Player update?

Tags: updates, flash

I know that Adobe is dropping support of this product at the end of the year.  However, I see an update was recently made available on the Windows platform but not on Linux?  Or, at least, I haven't gotten any updates when I run the Software Updater.  Is Adobe not releasing a maintenance update for Linux? I don't know where else to ask this question.

Comment: or perhaps this one? https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-adobe-flash-player-linux-terminal/

Comment: I just voted to reopen this question. Not that it matter so much, but it's crystal clear from the question that the OP is well aware of how to get Flash on Ubuntu. The whole issue is (or was) a delay of the `adobe-flashplugin` update.

Comment: Seems like a question that's no longer relevant, then.

Comment: @muru: True. Mostly me who got irritated with those who dismissed the question as a duplicate, seemingly without reading it. But yes, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you can see at https://get.adobe.com/se/flashplayer/about/ Adobe updates it for Linux too.

But the Canonical folks seem not be so fast with updating the `adobe-flashplugin` package as they used to be, and the latest `adobe-flashplugin` provides version `32.0.0.414` which unfortunately is not the latest Flash Player version.

One way to fix it for you is to download if from [here](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) and (assuming you use Firefox) manually replace `/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so` with the downloaded version of `libflashplayer.so`.

Comment: It looks like the update JUST dropped!

Comment: @Jaime: You are right. Good!